# How to copy a generated file from a GitHub Actions workflow to a Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, github-actions

I'm using a GitHub Actions to deploy to a Google Cloud Function. The steps in my workflow include:

```
steps:
    - name: "Checkout repository"
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    # Setup Python so we can install Pipenv and generate requirements.txt.
    - name: "Setup Python"
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.10' 

    - name: "Install Pipenv"
      run: |
          pipenv requirements > requirements.txt
          ls -la
          cat requirements.txt

    - name: "Generate requirements.txt"
      run: pipenv requirements > requirements.txt

    - id: "auth"
      name: "Authenticate to Google Cloud"
      uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v0"
      with:
        workload_identity_provider: "..."
        service_account: "..."

    - id: "deploy"
      uses: "google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v0"
      with:
        name: "my-function"
        runtime: "python310"
```

Once I've generated the `requirements.txt` file I want that to be deployed along with my application code (checked out in the step above). The `requirements.txt` file gets generated during the build but it never gets deployed. (Confirmed by looking at the source in Cloud Functions).

[image]

**How can I ensure this file is deployed along with my application code?**

**Update 1:**

Here is the output after listing the contents of the directory after generating requirements.txt:

```
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 6 runner docker 4096 Sep  6 20:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker 4096 Sep  6 20:38 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  977 Sep  6 20:38 .env.example
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  749 Sep  6 20:38 .gcloudignore
drwxr-xr-x 8 runner docker 4096 Sep  6 20:38 .git
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker 4096 Sep  6 20:38 .github
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  120 Sep  6 20:38 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  139 Sep  6 20:38 Pipfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  454 Sep  6 20:38 Pipfile.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 1276 Sep  6 20:38 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 5 runner docker 4096 Sep  6 20:38 app
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Sep  6 20:38 data
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 2169 Sep  6 20:38 main.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   27 Sep  6 20:38 requirements.txt
```

**Update 2**: Showing the contents of `requirements.txt` reveals it to only contain:

```
-i https://pypi.org/simple
```

No dependencies are included. This could well be the problem but I'm not yet sure why.

**Update 3**: The error shown in the deploy stage of the workflow is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'
```

This is because there is no `requirements.txt` file to install prior to running the function. `aiohttp` just happens to be the first dependency listed in my source code.

Comment: What is the error reported? list the contents of the directory where you are creating requirements.txt after creating it.

Comment: The error shown is with regard to a missing package (aiohttp in this case) but the cause is because I don't have a requirements.txt file in my root folder listing my dependencies. If I include one it works. Because I use Pipenv and I want to automate (not manually create before git committing) I'm looking for a way to automate the generation of a requirements.txt file as part of the build process. The  missing piece of the puzzle is how to get that file to deploy with the rest of my repo files.

Comment: List the contents of the directory after creating requirements.txt. The file is probably there but in the wrong location. Also, do not post images. Copy and paste the text into your question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Within the build itself? Is the best way to throw in an `ls` statement or is there a way to inspect?

Comment: Yes in the build step. Use the command `ls -la`.

Comment: Updated with the listed contents of the directory. The requirements.txt file appears to be there at that stage but not deployed.

Comment: What are the contents of requirements.txt? Use `cat requirements.txt`. Show the errors reported in the last step. What are the contents of `Pipfile`? My guess at this point is that the requirements.txt file does not contain all dependencies and your last step indicates the real problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247828/discussion-between-ianyoung-and-john-hanley).

Comment: Please use the techniques I have shown you to debug your problem. If going to chat is necessary that means your post does not have the details required to provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. That put me on the right track to figuring out the issue. Seems it was a problem with my Pipfile. requirements.txt now deploys with the rest of my code. Much appreciated.

Comment: @ianyoung, could you please post an answer with the solution that worked for you, in order to help any other users having the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @ianyoung, the problem was with the pip file.  The [requirements.txt](https://realpython.com/lessons/using-requirement-files/#:%7E:text=A%20Beginner%27s%20Guide%20to%20Pip&text=A%20requirements%20file%20is%20a,current%20projects%20dependencies%20to%20stdout%20.) was empty, the requirements file is a list of all of a project’s dependencies. This includes the dependencies needed by the dependencies. It also contains the specific version of each dependency, specified with a double equals sign (==).